# Jersey Client throws "Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity." when doing POST over proxy

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

In the following I'm using Jersey 2.25 to do a POST request over a proxy using ApacheConnector. Due to the proxy if I omit the configuration:

```
config.property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, RequestEntityProcessing.BUFFERED);
```

I will get the error `Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.`

Question: what is the correct way of handling proxy configuration with Jersey 2? My solution looks like a kludge to me.

```
package JerseyTest.one;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnectorProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestEntityProcessing;

public class Requester {
    public static String getPostResponseInOne(final String url, final String json) {
        final ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
        config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "http://proxyurl:8080");
        config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_USERNAME,"michael");
        config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_PASSWORD,"secret");
        config.property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, RequestEntityProcessing.BUFFERED);

        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

        final Builder builder = client.target(url).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        final String response = builder.post(Entity.json(json), String.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've received this error with a non-proxy, kerberos/SPNEGO client.  Adding the configuration property that you noted resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. actually what happens with this boolean config param is, that it creates a new byte Array for the `BufferedHttpEntity`, which is needed for the processing of the request.

You can find the code in the class `ApacheConnector` of the jersey-apache-connector-2.22.4.jar in `method getUriHttpRequest(...)`.